# Return IDs of inserted values PDO to MSSQL using ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, unixodbc

I need to get an array of id's of the subscribers added to the database within this function:

```
function insert_test($pdo, $fullname, $email) {
if ($SQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers ([dateAdded],[dateUpdated],[fullname],[email],[isActive]) VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fullname, :email, 1)")) {
    $SQL->bindValue(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $SQL->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $SQL->execute();

    return array('status'=> true);
} else {
    return array('status'=> false);
}
}
```

However I am stuggling with figuring out how to get the values and return them within the array like so:

```
return array('status'=> true,'ids'=> $ids);
```

I have read up and found that SCOPE_IDENTITY() is probably the most reliable way of getting these values but I don't know where to put it in this function to return the values that I need. The Primary key in the database is the id column.

Would it be something like this:

```
if ($SQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers ([dateAdded],[dateUpdated],[fullname],[email],[isActive]) VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fullname, :email, 1) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"))
```

And then bind a parameter after that called $ids or am I over thinking this completely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have tried using a similar function to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710280/getting-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-record-from-an-mssql-table-using-pdo-and-php) and was receiving an invalid cursor error so adapted it to look like this (notice the closeCursor was how to fix the invalid cursor error):

```
function insert_test($pdo, $fullname, $email) {
    if ($SQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers ([dateAdded],[dateUpdated],[fullname],[email],[isActive]) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fullname, :email, 1)")) {
        $SQL->bindValue(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQL->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQL->execute();
        $SQL->closeCursor();
        $ids = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return array('status'=> true, 'id' => $ids);
    } else {
        $pdo = null;
        return array('status'=> false);
    }
}
```

The return from this function is now this:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [id] => Array
        (
        ) 
)
```

So it seems the output is not working as it should? This is getting stranger and stranger...

Comment: Why you're using the plural form? Any reason you expect more than one id?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have outlined this in the question, I am going to be receiving an array of subscribers at once and need to get the id of each on once it is inserted so maybe this function would sit inside a foreach loop to gain each one? Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know ms sql, but probably so

Comment: Check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710280/getting-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-record-from-an-mssql-table-using-pdo-and-php)

Comment: Actually just tried this one and get this as a return: `SQLSTATE[24000]: Invalid cursor state: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys!

There was a problem with the position of the `closeCursor();` method the function now looks like this:

```
function insert_test($pdo, $fullname, $email) {
    if ($SQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers ([dateAdded],[dateUpdated],[fullname],[email],[isActive]) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fullname, :email, 1)")) {
        $SQL->bindValue(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQL->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $SQL->execute();    
        $ids = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $SQL->closeCursor();

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            return $id['id'];
        }

    } else {
        $pdo = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

So when `insert_test($pdo, $fullname, $email);` is within a for each loop containing the data being inserted the function returns each id as desired.

If anyone can see any inherent problems with this please let me know!