# Get last inserted id in mssql using unixodbc

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I want to connect to mssql server so I've use unixodbc and POD driver. now when i execute insert query i want last inserted_id so I've use PDO function `lastInsertId()` , and it is giving me error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support lastInsertId().

googling for hours i found solution to use, `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id`, this didn't help me it is giving me error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command

Can Anyone help me solve my problem? I want to get **last inserted id**

My PHP code is on linode server and my DB is MSSQL.

This is my insert function.

```
$resultOFP=$objDaMS->ManupulateData("INSERT INTO Offline_Patient 
(doctorid,firstname,lastname,mobile1,email,createdon,hsbit,clinicid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ",
array($DocID,$User_on_detail[0]['firstname'],$User_on_detail[0]['lastname'],
$User_on_detail[0]['mobile1'],$User_on_detail[0]['email'],date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),true,$AddId));
```

And this is my `ManupulateData()` function.

```
public function ManupulateData($query,$val=array()){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
            $stmt->bindParam($i+1, $val[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        if($this->queryDriver=="mssql"){
            //$stmt->closeCursor();
            return $this->db->query('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id');
            //return $this->db->lastInsertId(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else{
            return $this->db->lastInsertId(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
```

Seriously Need Help.

Comment: is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36013616/2207559

Comment: @atoms THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! You saved me. THANK YOU SO MUCH